# Stop Running a Procedure in Batch File

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, batch-file, return

I am creating a deployment package which will run a stored procedure that's in VSS. I am able to do this but my problem is this. I have more or less 30 databases which I need to deploy to and I only have two databases which doesn't need to get the update. With that, I included the following codes to the .sql file which the batch file runs:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('CONFIG') IS NULL OR  DB_NAME() LIKE '%SampleDB%'
BEGIN
    PRINT 'This is not a store database. Skipping this database.'
    SET NOEXEC ON
    RETURN
END

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE ID = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[sp_ThisIsMySampleProcedure]'))
     DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ThisIsMySampleProcedure]
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF 
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ThisIsMySampleProcedure]
-- Everything else follows...
```

This sql code runs perfectly on SQL Server. Whenever I run it against Sample DB, it automatically skips proceeding to the checking if the procedure exists and everything after that.

But whenever I try to run it against SampleDB using my batch file, it prompts the error message but continues to run the procedure disregarding my `RETURN` keyword. So the message would look like this:

> This is not a store database. Skipping this database.
>   Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Line 8
>   Cannot drop the procedure 'sp_ThisIsMySampleProcedure', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

I understand that the error message is correct because the procedure really doesn't exist on my SampleDB. But why does it still keep running when I have the `RETURN` keyword there after it satisfied the condition to skip running the entire script?

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

Okay, I think people doesn't understand me completely. This is the scenario: My procedure (see above) works well on SQL Server Management Studio. What I mean is that whenever I try to run it on SampleDB, it gives me the message `This is not a store database. Skipping this database.`

But whenever I try to run my Batch-File which executes this stored procedure, I get this message on the command prompt:

> This is not a store database. Skipping this database.
>   Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Line 8
>   Cannot drop the procedure 'sp_ThisIsMySampleProcedure', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Which basically means that the batch-file continued executing the whole SQL Script regardless that the first condition was satisfied.

My question is how do I make the batch-file know that whenever SQL Server throws the message `This is not a store database. Skipping this database.` the batch-file will immediately stop the execution of the sql file.

Answer (score 1):

First. The keyword `GO` divides the file into separate requests. Each request separately processed by the server. `RETURN` exits only from first request, other requests will be run.

Try this:

```
select 1
RETURN
select 2
go
select 3
go
```

Second, `SET NOEXEC ON` is dangerous thing, it blocks all subsequent execution. Try this:

```
select 1
SET NOEXEC ON
RETURN
select 2
go
select 3
go
SET NOEXEC OFF
go
```

You can create procedure on all servers, but return from it in the beginig if database name like something. Or you can remove `GO` and create stored proc with dynamic SQL:

```
IF DB_NAME() like '%mydb%'
BEGIN
    EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[my proc]
    AS 
    BEGIN 
        select 1
    END'
END
```

Comment: Thanks. But I don't think we are on the same page. Please see my edit above. Thanks.

Comment: OK. Lets read lines step by step. 1. `IF OBJECT_ID('CONFIG') IS NULL OR...` works fine 2. PRINT works. 3. `SET NOEXEC ON` works - all subsequent statement will only compile, not run. It's important. 4. `RETURN` does not work (it was only compiled) 5. `IF EXISTS ...` does not work - it was only parsed and compiled (effect of `SET NOEXEC ON`). 6. Query optimizer try to compile `DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ThisIsMySampleProcedure]` but it can not, because this proc is absent. You've got error.

Comment: But when you run `SET NOEXEC ON` in SQL Server Management Studio it acts in whole session, so nothing works after this statement